# Писать Э или Е?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, фонетика

Часто в русском языке пишется Е, а читается Э. А иногда не известно, какую букву писать. Например: "тест", "каратэ" и т.д. Есть ли какое-то правило на этот счет?

Comment: Очень много сложившихся проблем, связанных с этим правилом, поэтому проще всего писать так, как произносим: тЕкст, каратЭ, мЭрия, брЭйк, мЭйл, СтЭнли. И так далее. Откуда там заимствуется "е" - непонятно! Во многих словах вообще содержатся сочетания букв на английском: ...a..e, ..ai... Написание выдуманного "е" в заимствованных словах выглядит , как ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке много заимствованных слов, в которых произносится буква Э. Дело в том, что в большинстве языков, из которых в наш язык приходят слова, отсутствует мягкое Е, поэтому, несмотря на то, что в них пишется Е, читается Э.
Примеры: *те[Э]ст, те[Э]рмос, инте[Э]рне[Э]т*.
Однако в тех же заимствованных словах может звучать и Е. Тут все дело в сложившейся традиции произношения и, в принципе, нет жесткого правила.
Примеры: *те[Е]кст, те[Е]рмостат, се[Е]рия*.
Есть слова, которые произносятся и так, и эдак, например, "орхидея".

Comment: Здравствуйте приехали! С каких это пор в "термостате" Е мягкая? "Орхидея" тоже твёрдо.