# "Каратэ" или "карате"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: "каратэ" или "карате"?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/196/186102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно последней реформе можно писать Е - *карате*. Однако если говорить о более правильной передаче звучания слова, то все-таки - Э, поскольку в японском языке нет мягкого Е.

Comment: О какой реформе вы говорите?
Тут есть расхождения в словарях, но это дело очень давнее.
"современный" Лопатин даёт карате, но и у Зарвы, Аванесова и проч. - тоже карате.
Каратэ даёт только Кузнецов.

Answer (score 0):

С каких пор гласные могут быть мягкими? Речь идёт о предшествующих согласных!