# ФлЕшка или флЭшка?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Как правильно писать: "ФлЕшка" или "флЭшка"?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/196/186102

Answer (score 4):

Не нашёл ни одного словаря, где бы написание нормировалось, следовательно на данный момент допустимы оба варианта, что фиксирует например словарь синонимов http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/311024/%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0

Как видится мне, "флэшка" предпочтительнее, так как лучше передаёт звучание и оригинальное написание слова (flash (вспышка), a не flesh (плоть, мясо)), но написание "флешка" гораздо более частотное. В общем, решать вам самим, допустимы оба варианта.

Answer (score 4):

Честно говоря, я ни разу не встречала, чтобы слово "флешка" писали через Э. Поэтому, думаю, что нормативным тут можно считать то, что наиболее часто употребляется.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще по логике нужно писать "флэшка". Все-таки разница в произношении между "-ле-" и "-лэ-", ИМХО, должна быть. И мы можем ее выразить на письме. Поэтому согласен с ответами [@grumant](/users/1349/grumant) и [@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос спорный. С одной стороны, в русском языке Э в середине слов традиционно используется только в редких словах типа мэр или сэр, главным образом - как дань дифференцирующему принципу орфографии (сравните [он был] сер, мер - Р.п. от меры).

С другой - английское flash явно означает открытый непалатизирующий звук. Э точнее передаёт реальное произношение. Л там никак не мягкий.

Словари пока однозначно не фиксирую, согласен с Марк Из.

Я лично, пожалуй, за более русское написание - флешка.

Comment: Я тоже за написание "флешка". В русском языке таких заимствований  - с написанием Е после твердого - очень много: "темп", "тест" и т.п.

Comment: grumant, после гласной даже не рассматриваем.
остаётся из Вашего списка рэп, который в ряду мэров, сэров и сами знаете чего.

Answer (score 3):

А как это правильнее произносить: флешка или флэшка? Вероятно, флэшка. Поэтому и писать надо: флэшка, как я думаю

Answer (score 3):

Если по-русски, то "флэшка", т.к. в русском языке буквы ДОЛЖНЫ передавать звучание звуков в иностранных словах. Иначе впервые читающий это русский человек будет блеять.

Comment: Ничего они не должны иностранным словам (они и в, эээ, более русских словах не всегда передают -- какой звук передаёт буква Л в слове "солнце"?). Существуют два способа передачи иностранных слов русской графикой: транскрипция (передача звуков) и транслитерация (передача букв).

Comment: @Tanque Спасибо за напоминание материала первого курса инъяза.Транслитерация должна осуществляться в соответствии с фонетическими обычаями РУССКОГО языка.То есть не "МакдонаЛдс",а "МакдоналЬдс",не "РонаЛдо",а "РоналЬдо",включая ударения:не "кОлледж",а "коллЕдж",не "ФлОрида",а "ФлорИда" и др.Но в нынешней ситуации русского угара подражания перед иностранщиной происходит РОВНО НАОБОРОТ.Что касается "э",то из уважения к носителям ПРАВИЛЬНО было бы ТРАНСКРИБИРОВАТЬ, чтобы сразу произносить незнакомое слово не карикатурно.А правило "Е после твердых,если не..."- это для лукавых ученых степеней.

Answer (score 3):

В русском языке существует большое количество слов, в которых буква Е пишется после твердых гласных. Изменить что-либо в этой области не представляется возможным, так как заимствованные слова ведут себя непредсказуемо. Сначала звук Э всегда произносится твердо, а потом он может смягчаться или не смягчаться, но  при этом слово уже имеет определенную графику.

Поэтому буква Э пишется в тех случаях, когда требуется смысловое отличие заимствованного  слова от сходных  русских слов: мэр/мер, рэп/реп, сэр/сер.

Слово "флешка" закрепило для себя твердое произношение, отличать его графику от других слов  не требуется, поэтому пишется буква Е.

Флешка - это устройство с флеш-памятью (англ. flash memory — разновидность полупроводниковой технологии электрически перепрограммируемой памяти).  Также для сравнения: плеер - от англ. player.

Answer (score 1):

Флешка (от англ. flash — миг, мгновение, вспышка), также часто используется неверное написание «флэшка» — разговорный термин

Comment: Откуда дровишки? В смысле - инфа. 
Не очень понятно, на каком основании одно из написаний объявляется неправильным.  
Ясно. Википедия. Самая свободная от ответственности энциклопедия.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю тема разговора USB flash или Adobe flash.

**[flash](http://ru.forvo.com/search/flash/)** В оригинале носителем языка звучит [флашь], думаю от этого и надо плясать.

А **[flesh](http://ru.forvo.com/search/flesh/)** [флэшь] переводиться как плоть. И отношения к теме разговора не имеет.